Code executing inside of promise declarations at first instead of waiting for promise race
I have piece of code here where I have used Promises to make use the a timeout function resolves after 1 min if the reload function takes more than 1 min to execute, the problem I am facing is the code is entering the promise declarations initially and executing everything internally one by one. (Its hitting setTimeout first and later reload() and then finally promise.race). It should actually hit promise.race first and execute 2 promises simultaneously later. How to refactor this.
async function test() {
   
    const timerPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 60000, "Done"); // 
    });


    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        reload(); // 
        resolve("Successfull");  
    });

    const response = Promise.race([timerPromise, promise]).then((x) => {
        console.log(response)
    });
}

Thanks
It should actually first just initialize the const and then hit promise.race and execute 2 promises simultaneously later.
Edit : I am trying to wrap the promises in the functions so that it can  be called by promise.race() but this approach is not working as well , I observed that the timer is not returing back the promise at return timerPromise and the functionality is not working as I expected.

async function test() {

 async function promise1() {

     const timerPromise = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         setTimeout(resolve, 60000, "Done"); // 1 min Timer
     });
     return timerPromise
 }

 async function promise2() {
     const promise = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

         reload(); // Time and memory consuming func
         resolve("Successfull"); //completes without error  
     });
     return promise
 }

 const response = Promise.race([promise1(), promise2()]).then((x) => {
     console.log(response)
 });
}



It should actually first just initialize the const and then hit promise.race and execute 2 promises simultaneously later. ... when is later? there's nothing asynchronous about the code in const promise .. so why does it matter?

As in the promise constructor docs item #3 in the flow summary, the executor function passed into new Promise is executed immediately and synchronously.

@JaromandaX What is happening is the code is hitting setTimeout and later reload sequentially( the code is getting executed line by line) . I believe that the whole purpose of promise.race is to make the two promises run simultaneously and discards the output of the function or promise which returns the promise later. If i have misunderstood the concept of promises here, please help me out on how to achieve this functionality of the one I mentioned above.

no, the point of Promise.race is to resolve to the Promise that resolves first amongst the promises passed in - it does not control the execution of said Promises, since promises are a value, not a piece of code
